# no_device: yes not working while create an ami using Ansible

Tags: ansible, ec2-ami

I am trying to create an ami from an ec2 instance, I have four volumes attached to instance but I wanted choose particular device types without detaching volumes from instance while creating an ami using ansible, I have tried multiple scenarios like no_device: yes, and device_mapping: "{{ devices }}" nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I had the same error and I found the solution. There is an error in the module documentation.
You should use:

```
device_mapping:
  - device_name: /dev/sdb
    no_device: ""
```